# Resolve an explicit UPN to a implicit UNP (user pricipal name) in active directory

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, upn

Accourding to this; https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa380525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

There are two types of UPN's. (User pricipal name)

- implicit UPN
- explicit UPN (defined by the admin)

Is there a way to resolv the explicit UPN to the implicit UPN from a root domain?

I want to do this with system.directoryservices in vb.net, but c# tips are also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on ServerFault.

Comment: Well, I want to do it in vb.net. So, it does involve programming.

Comment: I see now that you tagged vb.net, but it wasn't explained inside the question, which was why I commented like that.  I apologize.